# ''A dynamical theory of the electromagnetic field'' who come the intrinsic energy equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

maybe my question looks simple but i get stuck.
Bellow i send you a photo from Maxwell's paper on dynamical theory of the electromagnetic field. I put in a red square the equation which i can't understand how come from the above one. If we suppose L,M,N as constant shouldn't the whole equation be zero? Where is my fault? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the equation above the one in the box (the equality is not explicity in the paper, but we know it's zero, right?): $$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \left(L x^2 + 2 M  x y + N y^2 \right) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{dL}{dt} x^2+ \frac{dM}{dt} x y + \frac{1}{2} \frac{dN}{dt} y^2 = 0$$.

If $L, M, N$ are constants, then $$\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{dM}{dt} = \frac{dN}{dt} = 0,$$ and only the term $$\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \left(L x^2 + 2 M  x y + N y^2 \right) =0 $$ 
 survives. Indeed, THIS should be zero, but note that **the boxed equation has no time derivative!** Using the fundamental theorem of calculus:$$ \int dt \frac{d}{dt}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\left(L x^2 + 2 M  x y + N y^2 \right) \right]= cte \equiv E $$

Therefore
$$\frac{1}{2} L x^2 +  M  x y + \frac{1}{2} N y^2= E .$$ 
Edit: I set the left-handed side to zero because the paper says these represent the work that is not converted into heat, so I believe they are assumed to be conserved.

Comment: The equation above the one in the box is the left side of the equation (8) from the paper which is equal to   ξx+ηy-H . Why we have to take it equal to zero. Thank for your answer.